# Regex Help:  Replacement using \W

Tags: regex

I am working with this as my test string:
**"butter butter butter1 butter_ .butter. butter"**

My goal is to replace any instance of "butter" or "butter" with a non-word character on either side of it with the text "yum".  I'd like to end up with a string that looks like this: **"yum yum butter1 butter_ .yum. yum"**

I'm struggling with this because when i build out my own regex i end up missing the first and last instances of "butter" and i cannot anchor the regex to the start/end as it will miss the instances of "butter" in the middle.

thank you!

Edit:

Javascript, Perl or Ruby are perfectly acceptable languages.  Sorry for leaving that out and thank you to those who answered w/ missing information.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: There are a gazillion regexp dialects, please tell which one you expect the answer to be in ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo ""butter butter butter1 butter_ butter butter"|perl -pe 's{\bbutter\b}{yum}'
```

Comment: The regex you provided works in a few different scripting languages i tried.  Thanks a lot... i had a complete misunderstanding of what \b was and now after seeing your work and looking it up... things clicked. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your regexp dialect, `(^|\W)butter(\W|$)` might do the trick. But `\b` might be more sensible.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html), using the character set `\b`. [Here's an example you'd use to match it](http://regexr.com?2va8c):

```
\bbutter\b
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it in c#

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\bbutter\b", RegexOptions.None);

var newString = regex(butterString, "yum");
```